# Why pictures in slider does not show correctly

Tags: vuejs2, slider, slideshow, swipe, swiper.js

I'm using vue-awesome-swiper and it shows several pictures per slide. What could be probable cause?

[image]

Here is my pug:
    .worklist_block-background
      swiper.gallery-top(:options='swiperOptionTop', ref='swiperTop')
        swiper-slide(v-for='(item, idx) in swiperItems' :key='idx'  :class=`'slide-'+(idx+1)`)
          img(:src='item.bigImage')
    .worklist_block-small
      swiper.gallery-thumbs(:options='swiperOptionThumbs', ref='swiperThumbs')
        swiper-slide.swiper__thumb-position(v-for='(item, idx) in swiperItems' :key='idx'  :class=`'slide-'+(idx+1)`)
          img(:src='item.smallImage')
        .swiper-button-next(slot='button-next')
        .swiper-button-prev(slot='button-prev')

and my data()

```
data: () => ({
swiperOptionTop: {
  setWrapperSize: true,
},
swiperOptionThumbs: {
  spaceBetween: 10,
  centeredSlides: true,
  slidesPerView: "auto",

  touchRatio: 0.2,
  slideToClickedSlide: true,
  observeParents: true,
  centeredSlides: true,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
},
```